# GNU Radio: tune_request with python

Tags: python, gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to make 2 TX 2 RX (MIMO) config with a USRP X310. I made the flowgraph for 2TX and 2RX config in GRC and generated the python script.

I have a question about tune request. In general with a 2 TX 2 RX config with python, there are 4 tune requests for 4 ports, which looks like

```
self.usrp_source0.set_center_freq(f, 0)
self.usrp_source0.set_center_freq(f, 1)
self.usrp_sink0.set_center_freq(f, 0)
self.usrp_sink0.set_center_freq(f, 1)
```

where `usrp_sink0` is the TX usrp object and `usrp_source0` is the RX usrp object.

Is it possible to define 1 tune request for all TXs and 1 tune request for all RXs like described below?

```
self.usrp_source0.set_center_freq(f, all_chan)
self.usrp_sink0.set_center_freq(f, all_chan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how the `usrp_source` block is written, you will only be able to send a command to a single channel at a time.

```
::uhd::tune_result_t
usrp_source_impl::set_center_freq(const ::uhd::tune_request_t tune_request,
                                  size_t chan)
{
  const size_t user_chan = chan;
  chan = _stream_args.channels[chan];
  const ::uhd::tune_result_t res = _dev->set_rx_freq(tune_request, chan);
  _center_freq = this->get_center_freq(user_chan);
  _tag_now = true;
  return res;
}
```

Notice that the `chan` parameter is of type `size_t`, so you can only pass in a single, non-negative integer.

I'm going to assume the sink has the same restriction.

https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-uhd/lib/usrp_source_impl.cc#L137

Comment: Indeed, that's the design. The idea behind this was that you either don't need the tuning to happen exactly time-aligned, in which case issueing four separate tune commands works, **or** you need time-alignment, making it necessary issue timed commands, which mean that no matter how many commands you issue, all commands with the same command time will happen at once.

Comment: Timed commands may have been what he was going for with the question, good point.